# What Is the significance of 'Sal Tree' in Buddhism?

Tags: texts

'Sal Tree' is revered by most people in sri lanka and most temple in the country grown it. Is this tree mentioned in the buddhist tradition?

Answer (score 2):

The Sal Tree has [Religious significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorea_robusta#Buddhism) in Buddhism. It was believed that the prince Siddhārtha was born under Sal Tree and Gautama Buddha did Parinibbana (DN 16) under the pair of Sal Trees.

The sal tree in Sri Lanka might be different from India and Burma but if people do respect to sal trees, it must be the two reasons above.